# pom expression version warning, or different versions error

Tags: tycho, p2

Our OSGi/RCP app uses an external project containing a pom file with 2 profiles: one default profile for the non-p2 build (packaging jar) and one profile for p2 builds (packaging eclipse-plugin).

When integrating that project in the RCP workspace in eclipse, the p2 profile is used, thus the project uses the manifest.

The pom looks like this:

```
<project ...>
    <groupId>group-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-id</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <packaging>${project.packaging}</packaging>
    . . .

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <project.packaging>jar</project.packaging>
                <project.version>4.0.brabchintextformat-SNAPSHOT</util.version> 
            </properties>
        . . .
        <profile>
            <id>p2</id>
            <activation>
                <file><exists>../p2</exists></file>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <project.packaging>eclipse-plugin</project.packaging>
                <project.version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</project.version>
                <tycho-version>0.24.0</tycho-version>
                <p2-repo-url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/</p2-repo-url>
            </properties>
            . . .
```

and the MANIFEST.MF has version 0.0.0.qualifier

Invoking mvn install with that setup works, but it warns about the fact that the version is not a constant:

```
'version' contains an expression but should be a constant
```

- Alternative 1: do not use the version property, and try to use the same constant in both the pom and the manifest. But that is not possible because the version number format that would be set as a constant is not compliant with the version number scheme of OSGi.
- Alternative 2: define the tycho.versions.plugin in the p2 profile,
  and set the versions before the build. I do not like that because it
  forces local updates to that project that may mistakenly be committed
  and pushed to the repository.
- Alternative 3: use a separate pom file (pom-p2.xml): That does not
  work because eclipse won’t allow to import it as a maven project.
- Alternative 4: use the tycho.pomless plugin: That does not work
  because if the pom.xml file exists, it uses it (there is no
  ‘ignorePOM’ flag).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, our context is unusual. This external project's version is conventionally managed outside of the context that it is used here. But its version is not compatible with OSGi. So in your question #4, the reason is that the tycho plugin refuses to build the jar if the pom version is not the same as the version in the manifest. Both must be the same, but the manifest does not accept the format of the one committed in the project. Therefore, when using that project in RCP, we need to forge the pom version as described above.

Comment: Alternative 5: ignore the warning -- you have a crazy and wonderfully unique set of constraints and you are better off being reminded of that every time you do a build so that there's no doubt that you're doing something unusual -- that's what the warning is for. It's useful, you shouldn't be jumping through hoops to remove it.

Comment: Yeah, but this external project also produces this warning (version not constant) when built by the owners. Maybe there is no solution other than making this project OSGi/p2 conformant.